# How do I prevent the rows from "items do not exist" to appear in the EXTRACT csv?

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit iMacros 10.0.2
Good day,  My datasource is a .csv that contains the terms I am using to search in a website. The results of searches are individual pages, depending upon the search term.  It happens that for some of the search terms there exist no individual pages and the website where I am searching shows a "0 items exist" message.  iMacros still extracts data according with the its tag positioning and the DOM structure of the "0 items exist" page or gets #EANF# in the cases it does not find a tag match on the page. Then, iMacros saves the extracted that in a row of the extraction csv.   I wish to exclude from CODE: SELECT ALL SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT .csv the rows that belong to the "0 items exist" webpage (in other words my extracted CSV to show only the complete data extracted from the website).
**Question:** How do I prevent the rows from "items do not exist" to appear in the EXTRACT csv?  What is the condition to be placed looking like?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this workaround:

```
SET csvFolder EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/#EANF#/)) ? 'noSuchFolder' : '*';")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{csvFolder}} FILE=extracts.csv
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using JavaScript. If the search not matched the below code will write "Search not matched" in the csv, otherwise it will write the Search text

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:****** EXTRACT=TXT\n"); //here you need to mention your extract tag

        var tmp = iimGetLastExtract().trim();

        if(tmp.indexOf("EANF")!= -1)
        {       
        var Val1='Search not matched';
        iimSet("Val1",Val1);
        iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{Val1}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Searchextract.csv");
        }
        else 
        {
        iimSet("tmp",tmp);
        iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{tmp}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Searchextract.csv");
        };
```

If you want to store only the search text, try the below code

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:****** EXTRACT=TXT\n"); //here you need to mention your extract tag

        var tmp = iimGetLastExtract().trim();

        if(tmp.indexOf("EANF")== -1)
        {       
        iimSet("tmp",tmp);
        iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{tmp}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Searchextract.csv");
        };
```